# Person who consumes in a restaurant or bar

Tags: nouns, translation

What's the word that refers to the person that consumes dishes and/or cocktails in a bar or restaurant?

In Spanish, it would be "Comensal". Google translate suggests me "diner", which might cause confusion on my project. Is there a better word for it?

Comment: In English, it's *customer* or *patron* (or less often, *guest*).

Comment: Welcome to the site. :) Part of your confusion might be due to synonyms and spellings: *diner* (someone who dines), *diner* (a restaurant originally built like a train car serving food), and *dinner* (the meal). The last of which is even more confusing.

Comment: What is *diner* not the best word? You should not confuse *diner* with *dinner*.

Comment: The person is a _customer_ no matter what he consumes. But he is a _diner_ only if he eats solid food; otherwise he's just a patron of the bar (or in cruder language, a _drinker_).

Answer (score 2):

'Diner', 'customer', 'patron', 'guest' or the more technical 'cover' might all be acceptable. Other than that, try a thesaurus of any of those words.

Comment: Cover means the place setting for each diner, which of course might be used metaphorically for the diner him/herself.  But if so, that's very peculiar to the profession; it is jargon that is hardly in wide use among the general population.

Comment: aaaaaaa-men.  Never heard "cover" used to refer to a restaurant customer, and if I did hear it, it would go right past me.  It must be jargon, like referring to a customer as "table 12".

Answer (score 1):

A **"customer"** is a general term -  a person who purchases goods or services from another; buyer; patron. [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/customer)

A **guest** may be what you're looking for:  "one who pays for meals or accommodations at a restaurant, hotel, or other establishment; a patron."  [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/guest)